# Swift 3, NS Generic Exception - NSArrayM was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, swift

Error:

> 2017-07-13 16:02:03.635000 bihamkapp[1461:1448858] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '***
>   Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17005f680> was mutated while being
>   enumerated.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1820b91b8 0x180af055c 0x1820b8c00 0x100176584 0x100176030 0x18c1fb934 0x1001484bc 0x101103ae4
>   0x18530ef24 0x18530edd0 0x182326094 0x18204ee50 0x182067218
>   0x1820669cc 0x1820644b0 0x181f922b8 0x183a46198 0x187fd97fc
>   0x187fd4534 0x10007dfac 0x180f755b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Code:

```
func callWS(){
        let  url = URL(string: "some url")

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)  

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {

            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")
            }
            else
            {
                if let content = data
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[String:AnyObject]]

                        self.myCopyJSON = myJSON!

                        for post in self.myCopyJSON {

                            var icon = post["type"]

                            if let checkNull = post["type"] as? NSDictionary {
                                print(checkNull)
                            }
                            else{
                                let tipRadara:Int = icon as! Int

                                switch tipRadara
                                {
                                case 1:
                                    icon = "radar_stacionarni" as AnyObject
                                case 2:
                                    icon = "radar_najavljeni" as AnyObject
                                default:
                                    icon = "" as AnyObject
                                }

                                let title = post["title"]
                                let coordinates = post["coordinates"]
                                let text = post["text"]

                                if((coordinates?.length)! > 0 && (title?.length)! > 0 && (icon?.length)! > 0){
                                    let coord_2 = coordinates?.components(separatedBy: ",")

                                    let coord_1_part: String = coord_2![0]
                                    let coord_2_part: String = coord_2![1]

                                    var stanjeMarker: NMAMapMarker?

                                    let coordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: Double(coord_1_part)!, longitude: Double(coord_2_part)!)
                                    stanjeMarker = NMAMapMarker(geoCoordinates: coordinates)

                                    let pdfImageIcon: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithPDFNamed(icon as! String, fitSize: CGSize(width:100, height:100))!
                                    stanjeMarker?.icon = pdfImageIcon
                                    stanjeMarker?.title = title as! String
                                    stanjeMarker?.textDescription = text as! String
                                    self.mapView.add(stanjeMarker!)

                                }
                                else {
                                    print("else length > 0")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch {                     
                    }
                }
            }
        })      
        task.resume()
    }

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    mapView.useHighResolutionMap = true 
    mapView.zoomLevel = 7 
    mapView.set(geoCenter: NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 43.915886, longitude: 17.67907600000001), animation: .none) 
    mapView.copyrightLogoPosition = NMALayoutPosition.bottomCenter 
    self.mapView.delegate = self 
    callWS() 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `callWS()`?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mapView.useHighResolutionMap = true
        mapView.zoomLevel = 7
        mapView.set(geoCenter: NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 43.915886, longitude: 17.67907600000001), animation: .none)
        mapView.copyrightLogoPosition = NMALayoutPosition.bottomCenter
        
        self.mapView.delegate = self
        
        callWS()
    }

Comment: code seems to work for me. Make sure you are not trying to append any data to myCopyJSON from elsewhere in the controller

Comment: @kathayatnk Code doesn' work once in 3 times. After I close the activity and open it again, and so on 5-6 times, this error occurs ... can there be a reason for a memory error? I only get this error when I have mapView.add(Marker) in code...When I comment it, everything is fine.

Comment: Ok, Maybe that exception is thrown from some other section of code. Are you using other arrays? You said this works when add marker is commented, What happens when mapViews delegates are called try adding breakpoints on them.

Comment: @kathayatnk file.txt
http://www88.zippyshare.com/v/leYf90m9/file.html